# Looking for an alternative to Outrec for 12.10

Tags: 12.10, sound, software-recommendation, streaming

I tried to install Outrec on 12.10, following any of the instructions available online. Unfortunaly, the dependencies are broken and OutRec would not install from the sources.

Is there any alternative to record all sounds coming through Ubuntu (as non-standard streamcasts or skype calls)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the standard Ubuntu gnome-sound-recorder or Audacity to do that. You just have to tweak PulseAudio to fetch the sound directly from the soundcard.

Here is how to (in German): 
http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/PulseAudio#Audiostream-aufnehmen